# How to change contant value in unit test?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a unit test that look like this:

```
describe('my test', function() {
    var rootScope, $compile, mConfig;

    beforeEach(function() {
        module('app');

        module(function($provide) {
            $provide.value('MyConfig', {myvalue:"first"});
        });

        inject(function($rootScope, _$compile_,MyConfig) {
            rootScope = $rootScope;
            $compile = _$compile_;
            mConfig = MyConfig;
        });
    });

    it('test contant value', function() {
        mConfig.myvalue = "first";
        var scope = rootScope.$new();
        var element = angular.element('<div my-directive></div>');
        element = $compile(element)(scope);

        // when mConfig.myvalue = "first"
        expect($scope.value).toBe("one");

        // when mConfig.myvalue = "second"
        expect($scope.value).toBe("two");

        // when mConfig.myvalue = "thrid"
        expect($scope.value).toBe("three");

    });
});
```

How can I change the constant value along the way to do the testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure but if your directive is dependent on the intial mConfig value, then you can try to create the directive multiple times and assert

```
it('test contant value', function() {
        mConfig.myvalue = "first";
        var scope = rootScope.$new();
        var element = angular.element('<div my-directive></div>');
        element = $compile(element)(scope);

        // when mConfig.myvalue = "first"
        expect($scope.value).toBe("one");

        mConfig.myvalue = "second";
        var scope = rootScope.$new();
        element = angular.element('<div my-directive></div>');
        element = $compile(element)(scope);
        // when mConfig.myvalue = "second"
        expect($scope.value).toBe("two");

        mConfig.myvalue = "third";
        var scope = rootScope.$new();
        element = angular.element('<div my-directive></div>');
        element = $compile(element)(scope);
        // when mConfig.myvalue = "thrid"
        expect($scope.value).toBe("three");

    });
```